# How to work with generic vars in c# or CS1503

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

I write a HashTable with linked list.

This is code of node element

```
    class ListNode<T>
    {
        public T value{get; set;}
        public ListNode<T> next{get; set;}

        public void Insert(T newValue){
            value = newValue;
        }
    }
```

And this is Linkedlist implementetion

```
    class LinkedL<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        ListNode<T> head;
        ListNode<T> tail;

        public void Add(T newVal){
            ListNode<T> node = new ListNode<T>();
            node.Insert(newVal);

            if (head == null)
                head = node;
            else
                tail.next = node;
            
            tail = node;
        }
     }
```

And finally my HashTable with a simple hash-func X % N

```
    class HashTable 
    {
        int N;
        public LinkedL<ListNode<int>>[] values; 

        public HashTable(int n){
            N = n;
            values = new LinkedL<ListNode<int>>[N];
         }

        public void Insert(int newValue){
            var mod = newValue % N;
            values[mod].Add(newValue);
        }       
    }
```

When i try to Insert(int) to a HashTable instance compiler throw a CS1503 error

`cannot convert from "int" to "this.ListNode<int>"`

This is a little bit confusing.

Comment: Your `LininkeL` uses `ListNode` internally so you should do `LinkedL<int>[]` instead of `LinkedL<ListNode<int>>[]`

Comment: Also you don't need that `Insert` method on `ListNode` as you can just set the `value` directly and the name is confusing as you're setting a value not inserting one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150381/generic-linked-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because when you do this `values[mod]` you are accessing a `LinkedL<ListNode<int>>` so, the `Add` method requires a `ListNode<int>` to be added.

I think the confussion is here `public LinkedL<ListNode<int>>[] values;` in your declaration.

You are addind `[]` at the end. so, it means you are declaring an `Array` of `LinkedL` not just a `LinkedL`

Comment: and why `Add` method requires a `ListNode<int>`?. It's not what i want or even expect.

Comment: @Noaztec It requires it because you told it the `LinkedL` would contain values of `ListNode<int>` when you meant to tell it that it would contain values of `int`

Comment: Thanks @juharr and sebrojas, I think I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

The type of `values[mod]` is of type `LinkedL<ListNode<int>>`. Therefore you need to add an `ListNode<int>` item.

First of all, your ListNode needs to have an constructor, not an `Insert` method:

```
class ListNode<T>
{
    public T value { get; set; }
    public ListNode<T> next { get; set; }

    public ListNode(T newValue)
    {
        value = newValue;
    }
}
```

Then the `Add method should be:

```
public void Add(T newVal)
{
    ListNode<T> node = new ListNode<T>(newVal);
    ...
}
```

Then your `Insert` method from the `HashTable` class needs to be like this:

```
public void Insert(int newValue)
{
   var mod = newValue % N;
   ListNode<int> node = new ListNode<int>(newValue);
   values[mod].Add(node);
}
```